# link_to with block in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have seen this code in this repository:

```
<%= link_to(:controller => 'account', :action => 'select', :account_id => account.customer_id) { account.customer_id.to_s } %>
    (<%= account.login %> / <%= account.company_name %> )
```

This actually converts to the following HTML:

```
<a account_id="8282277272" action="select" controller="account">8282277272</a>
        ( loginname / companyname )
```

I am wondering how would you pass a block to link_to in order to make this work?

Comment: I don't follow.  Why would a block be needed.  The code you posted doesn't use or need a block.

Comment: as you can see { account.customer_id.to_s } is passed to link_to. I am not sure why the developer does that, but I know a block can be passed.

Comment: try with url_for: `link_to( url_for(:controller => 'account', :action => 'select', :account_id => account.customer_id) ) { account.customer_id.to_s }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. The stuff inside the "do..end" will be put inside the a tag.

```
<%= link_to(:controller => 'account', :action => 'select', :account_id => account.customer_id) do %>
    (<%= account.login %> / <%= account.company_name %> )
<% end %>
```

It should produce

```
<a href="<path to controller with account_id parameter>">
    (username / Company, Inc.)
</a>
```

What was happening in your original code was that the expression `{ account.customer_id.to_s }` was being passed as the block to link_to. If you want the customer id to be displayed along with the "login" and "company_name", put it inside the block.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <%= link_to(account_select_path(:account_id => account.customer_id.to_s)) do%>
      <%= account.customer_id.to_s %>
   <%end%>   
   (<%= account.login %> / <%= account.company_name %> )
```

and in your config/routes.rb, in the beginning of the file, add

```
match 'account/select' => "account#select", :as => :account_select
```

Comment: Vimsha, I was actually refering to: { account.customer_id.to_s } -- That's a block inside the link_to right? But is just not creating the <a> element correctly.

Comment: This is actually not creating the link correctly either. <a account_id="123123213" action="select" controller="account">
        1231321321
</a>

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: <a href="/account/select?account_id=12321312312">12312313123</a>